# Error installing QConsolidate?

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation

I tried to install QConsolidate by placing the plugin folder ("qconsolidate-master") in:
c:\users\.qgis2\python\plugins\

but received an error "Couldn't load plugin qconsolidate-master due an error when calling its classFactory() method" when starting QGIS. I am using QGIS 2.4.0-Chugiak.

Is there an incompatibility issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the QConsolidate plugin in the Plugin Manager list after enabling searching for experimental plugins under "Settings". Plugin Manager got it from the repository and installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the plugin installer to install packages it will take care of everything.  If you do need to manual install you will need to remove the `-` from the file name:

`qconsolidate`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it did not solve the problem. Also, QConsolidate does not appear in the Plugin list, and it is labeled as "Experimental". It appears there is a module missing from the code: In the Plugins menu I see an error "No module named ui_qconsolidatedialogbase".

Comment: Also, the code repository is supposedly "http://github.com/alexbruy/qconsolidate". When I add this address as a new plugin repository in QGIS, I receive error "Status code: 301 moved permanently". So I can't seem to install this plugin neither manually nor with the plugin installer.